# Detecting usb devicy type using udev

Tags: usb, udev

I'm writing a program using `libudev` to detect USB device connection on system.
I want to know what is the type of each device connected.
I think the udev doesn't clearly says what is the type of the usb, for example I want to know if connected device is a printer or a webCam or a keyboard.
How can I do that? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of any USB device is identified using the `bDeviceClass` and `bDeviceSubClass` attributes, whose values are defined by the relevant USB protocol specifications: see https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes for a list of class codes.

If a USB device has multiple functions, you might have to examine the `bInterfaceClass` and `bInterfaceSubClass` attributes too, to identify the individual functions.

And if the class code turns out to be `0xff`, which means "vendor-specific", you'll most likely need to identify the actual device model (using the `idProduct` and `idVendor` attributes) to figure out what the device is.

Comment: Good. I will test it and feedback. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

> I think the udev doesn't clearly says what is the type of the usb,

udev reports out basically everything the kernel knows about the USB device in form of attributes, e.g. the vendor and product ID, and the class. Look e.g. at [these example rules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev#udev_rule_example) and walk the attributes on your USB devices to see more.

There is also already quite a bit of automation going on for e.g. keyboard (HID) USB devices and cameras, so whatever it is you are writing, make sure it fits with the existing udev rules and kernel actions.